# How to make OAuth redirection work with # in the Redirect URL?

Tags: web, redirect, oauth-2.0, slack, slack-api

I am trying to integrate my web application with slack using their OAuth APIs.
Our Web App has a # in its URL. - example.org/#/path
But Slack doesn't support Redirect URLs with a #. The part after the # is getting skipped.
What can I do to bypass the # and make the redirect URL work correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had similar issues where not all auth servers support the # character but you want to use hash based routing in the web UI.

**LOGOUT,**

In my case I wanted a post logout redirect URL of #loggedout but AWS did not allow me to configure it. So instead I configured:

- A post logout path of [/logged out.html](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/loggedout.html)
- This ran a [simple script to change the hash fragment](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/dist/loggedOut.js)

**LOGIN**

For login redirect URIs you can store the hash fragment in session storage before the redirect and restore it afterwards, as in the startLogin and handleLoginResponse methods of [this source file](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/web/webAuthenticator.ts)